# How much more efficient is building a recordset with newquery vs a union & connecting to database?

Tags: sql, database, coldfusion

How more efficient is building the query using queryNew()? I recently came across code creating a db call for a "dummy query" that didn't connect to any table like this:

```
<CFQUERY NAME="IncludeList" ....>
Select 0 as code, 'Exclude' as description
UNION ALL
Select 1 as code, 'Include' as description
</CFQUERY>
```

VS

```
<cfset IncludeList = queryNew("code, description","Integer, VarChar")>
<cfset newrow = queryaddrow(IncludeList, 2)>
<cfset temp = querysetcell(IncludeList, "code", 0, 1)>
<cfset temp = querysetcell(IncludeList, "description", "Exclude", 1)>
<cfset temp = querysetcell(IncludeList, "code", 1, 2)>
<cfset temp = querysetcell(IncludeList, "description", "Include", 2)>
```

Comment: benchmark them and u shall see? :)

Comment: lol, probably the only way. I was hoping for maybe a more general reason why one is better than the other if nobody has stats.

Comment: Why would you even need a query for such simple data?  I'd think a struct would be preferable, no?

Comment: @Todd - I thought that also. Digging a little deeper, I found they are using a cfselect with the query information.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid database connections.

For QofQ (i.e. `dbtype="query"`), while it seems like a good idea, in practice I've seen servers under load crash when multiple requests all hit the same QofQ. Based on stack traces, it appears the QofQ implementation single threads, blocking other threads.

On the other hand I also have code doing the `querySetCell()` thing and that has not been a performance issue.

Comment: Also remember that QoQ still runs SQL against a database (on Railo at least).  the record set is stored in an H2 database and the SQL is run against that.

Comment: I'm sure it does behind the scenes, but I'm assuming the DB is in process, so in theory shouldn't have the same penalty. However Adobe implementation has the issue I've described.

Answer (score 1):

Limiting Database calls would should always be preferred.

Comment: actually, wouldn't that be dbtype="query"?  No Database call needed either way, but in theory, CF would need relatively more effort to decode your SQL, compare to calling querySetCell() multiple times

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to use QueryNew over a QoQ.  It'll give you more flexibility in the long run.

Incidentally you know you don't have to assign functions like querysetcell to a 'temporary' variable:

```
<cfset temp = querysetcell(IncludeList, "code", 0, 1)>
```

You can just do:

```
<cfset querysetcell(IncludeList, "code", 0, 1)>
```